# Convergence of $\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^\alpha |\ln^\beta(x)|}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I know that $\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha\ln^\beta(x)}$ is
$i)$ Convergent if $\alpha\gt1$, $\forall\beta$
$ii)$Convergent if $\beta\gt1$ for $\alpha=1$
$iii)$Divegent if $\alpha\lt1$,$\forall\beta$
Now i am trying to understand what happens if i have same situation with interval other interval,say $(0,2)$.Can something similar be formulated for $\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^\alpha\ |ln^\beta(x)|}$?

Comment: $(\ln \, x)^{\beta}$ is not defined for $x<1$. If you replace $\ln\, x$ by $\ln\, |x|$ then the answer is: convergent for $\alpha <1$, divergent for $\alpha >1$, convergent for $\alpha =1,\beta >1$. divergent for $\alpha=1,\beta \leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes,exactly.but can this formulation be applied to $\int_0^2 \frac{|\ln^{\alpha-{2\over3}}(x)|}{x^\alpha}$?.For question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091996/convergence-of-int-0-infty-frac-lnx2-over32-ln-alpha-2-over3?noredirect=1#comment6374953_3091996

Comment: Your title and the question are at odds.